# What is the behavior of ShowAlways property in tooltip?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

What is the behavior of ShowAlways property of tooltip?

When the ShowAlways is enabled and tooltip is shown and the form is minimized, the tooltip window also gets minimized or hidden.

Could anyone please update the behavior?

Comment: Have you looked at the MSDN documentation?

Comment: You can check that in few minutes. Even writing this question took longer than if you would check that by hand ( manually )...

Comment: Update the behavior? Are you expecting someone to change the .NET source code?

Comment: I could not get the point of parentcontrol is active, because when i shown tooltip for a control and hides the parent control(form) , the tooltip window is hided

Answer (score 0):

[ToolTip.ShowAlways Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.showalways(v=vs.110).aspx)

Gets or sets a value indicating whether a ToolTip window is displayed, even when its parent control is not active.

Comment: I could not exactly get the point of parent control is not active.

Comment: @Amal, the parent control is whichever control holds the ToolTip, like a TextBox or a Label.

Comment: So i have added a tooltip for button, even when i leave the button, the tooltip wont hide?

Comment: @Amal No. If you switch applications. Say your application is running and you point at the button and then the tooltip comes up and if you press alt + tab the tool tip will still be there for the time duration allotted to it

Comment: And since you're minimizing the application you're basically leaving the control (in your case button) to click the minimize button and so it gets hidden. Unless you dont move your mouse of the control and perform some action the tool tip will remain.

Comment: @AdarshRavi - Its not working. I have shown tooltip for one button and press Alt+Tab, the tooltip is hided with application switch over with ShowAlways enabled too.

Comment: Trying adding this to your code toolTip.AutoPopDelay = 10000;

Comment: This will keep the tooltip active for 10 secs and after that it gets hidden

Comment: @AdarshRavi - your second comment explains the correct behavior. I got the point of ShowAlways

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: @AdarshRavi - What if we set AutoPopDelay = 0

Comment: @Amal You could just try it in your code than asking me

Comment: @AdarshRavi - I have tried, but tooltip is showing for some time even when i set AutoPopDelay= 0.

Comment: so i just asked for behavior, is there any behavior of setting to default value of AutoPopopup delay to some value when value is 0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142617/discussion-between-adarsh-ravi-and-amal).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there could be any other better documentation about the property than [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.showalways(v=vs.110).aspx)

MSDN states With the ShowAlways property, you can display a ToolTip window even when the container of the ToolTip is not active. It does not say ToolTip will be displayed even after minimized. Moreover, ToolTip is after all exist in the form. If the form is minimized then how ToolTip alone will be shown?

Comment: I have set tooltip for button and disabled the button and tooltip is not showing.

Comment: I have set tooltip for button and the button is enabled, on mousehover of button the tooltip is shown and the tooltip is hided when leaving the control.